# Set org.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser in build.xml

Tags: cxf

I want to set this system property in a `build.xml` script before using `CXF` to generate stubs using `WSDL2Java`. I'm aware of the security risks. How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434052/failed-to-parse-wsdl-during-deploying-app-on-jboss-maybe-woodstox/24450285#24450285

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the usage of `<sysproperty>` in the Ant manual for [Java Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).

Comment: how to set it on maven project?